# WCAG 2.0 and Speech recognition, is it A, AA or AAA

Tags: accessibility, speech-recognition, wcag2.0

I want to ask you, where dose speech recognition software stands in web accessibility. What i mean is, is it part of the WCAG A, or AA, or AAA. 
I tried to understand what W3C are explaining in here: http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/Overview.php

but i got lost around 5 times. The reason why I am asking, is because my client is asking if we are supporting A or AA level, and I have the feeling that speech recognition software is under AAA. If somebody can help me it will be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speech recognition isn't really a WCAG requirement.  It's usually a third party software that you can use to access applications using speech.  Do a google search on Dragon Naturally Speaking as an example.

If you have a website or a web application, you can see if your site is WCAG A or AA compliant by going through the criteria for those two levels.  There's nothing that specifically says it must work with speech recognition software.

However, by complying to the A and AA criteria, it significantly increases the chances that your app will work with speech recognition.  Especially 4.1.2 Name, Role, Value.